# Facebook API - Get comments

Tags: php, api, facebook

Our business has a Facebook Fan Page. The fan page doesn't seem to generate any emails to us when updates are made to the page, whether someone adds a new status or someone comments on one of the statuses etc.

Currently, we are running a very crude script to grab the content of the page and then use regular expressions to get the information we require. Obviously this is not fool proof and I'm looking into alternatives to this method.

I've been looking at the facebook API and wonder if the rest server might be an option. I cannot, however, seem to find out how to return information of fan page statuses and their comments. Is anyone able to direct me how to use the API to retrieve this information. I am an admin of the fan page. The programming language I'm using is PHP.

Many thanks.

Comment: Pages don't have a function to get status. http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Pages.getInfo

You can check what function available in facebook API
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API

Answer (score 1):

Actually the list of messages at page named not "comments" but "stream posts". so you should retrieve that postings via [Stream.get](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.get)

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution in using Facebook's FQL, which I have used through their API